# How to implement a property that draws from a certain source until it is set directly in Kotlin?

Tags: properties, kotlin

I currently have a property declared like this:

```
class Foo(val base : FooBase){
    var _number: Int? = null

    override var number: Int
        get() = _number ?: base.number
        set(value) {_number = value}
}
```

However, I have a lot of properties like this, leading to quite a bit of code duplication. Is there a way to avoid this? I understand that property delegation is a way to do this, but I am unsure how to implement `ReadWriteProperty<...>` correctly. How do I use the "property" value, if I'm supposed to use it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a performance improvement over the Yoav Sternberg's answer. As you see, it is less generic, but it avoids auto-boxing for ints:

```
class IntUninitializedProperty(private val getter: () -> Int) {
    private var isInitialised = false
    private var value: Int = 0

    fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Int = if(isInitialised) value else getter()

    fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: Int) {
        this.value = value
        isInitialised = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a class that extends `ReadWriteProperty` that provides the functionality (Code sample is based on unsafe lazy implementation)

```
class UninitializedProperty<T>(private val getter: () -> T) : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> {
    var _value: Any? = UNINITIALIZED_VALUE

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = if(_value === UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) getter() else _value as T

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        _value = value
    }

   private object UNINITIALIZED_VALUE
}
```

Next, define a helper method in order to keep constancy with standards delegates like `lazy`:

```
fun <T> uninitialized(getter: () -> T): ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> = UninitializedProperty(getter)
```

Now you can use it:

```
class Foo(val base: FooBase) {
    override var number: Int by uninitialized { base.number }
}
```

**Note:** The class is not thread safe.

Check the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) for more info about delegation.

Comment: I would recommend putting  `private object UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` inside `UninitializedProperty`, not alongside it

Comment: The implementation has a bug. What if it is initialized with `null`? To fix it, you need to compare `_value` with `UNINITIALIZED_VALUE`, not with `null`.